# Getting all the messages of a channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Getting all the messages of a channel. I want to get messages from a announcement channel in my server and show it in a embed . My idea is that i announce updates in my server's channel and i have made a command `updates` for now i am doing it manually but is there a way to do it ? I know to get the last message using this code but what about all messages

```py
@client.command(
    name='getlastmessage')
async def client_getlastmessage( ctx, ID):
    """Get the last message of a text channel."""
    channel = bot.get_channel(int(ID))
    if channel is None:
        await ctx.send('Could not find that channel.')
        return
    # NOTE: get_channel can return a TextChannel, VoiceChannel,
    # or CategoryChannel. You may want to add a check to make sure
    # the ID is for text channels only

    message = await channel.fetch_message(
        channel.last_message_id)
    # NOTE: channel.last_message_id could return None; needs a check

    await ctx.send(
        f'Last message in {channel.name} sent by {message.author.name}:\n'
        + message.content
    )
```

**EDIT :**
After getting two answers I tried this

```py
channel=client.get_channel(929329917894737970)
async for message in channel.history(limit=2):
    # do something with all messages
    content = message.content # get content
    await ctx.send(content)
```

This works fine unless there is an embed in the channel , how can i send something if it is a embed or send it's description .
2. Another method I tried

```
history = await ctx.channel.history(limit=3).flatten()
await ctx.send(history)
```

Result
`[<Message id=x channel=<TextChannel id=0000 name='terrasect' position=5 nsfw=False news=False category_id=jjjj> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=000<Member id=00000 name='SniperXi199' discriminator='0000' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=912559425921892392 name='Zionic BOT TESTERS' shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=4>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0> components=[]>]`
Note I have removed some crucial information like id etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be looking for this command, [channel.history()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=text%20channel#discord.TextChannel.history)

```py
async for message in channel.history(limit=200):
    # do something with all messages
    content = message.content # get content
```

Comment: Hello , i tried it and it sent this in this format
`[<Message id=929731766862905434 channel=<TextChannel id=911864429963001876 name='〔〕bot-command' position=13 nsfw=False news=False category_id=911864409939394590> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=900992402356043806 name='SniperXi199' discriminator='2209' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=911847883840552970 name='NeoLife Network' shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=19>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0> components=[]>` i tried both yours and Georgiadis's method can u help me get the message content

Comment: Did you add `message.content` in the for loop to get the content?

Comment: Thank you but it doesnt seems to work correctly can u give me your discord so i can send the errors and seek guidance

Comment: Just edit all new information in your post, then everyone can see if they can help you

Comment: Ok thanks i will do it after some time

Comment: Please remember to always include every error here and don't move the conversation to a place other from here.

Comment: Oh yes , just ediitng the question with all the details

Comment: Please check out the edited question , my main question is if there is a embed it raises an error saying Cant send an empty message which is okay but how do i make it send the description or title of the embed or atleast send that "There is a embed

Comment: Each message has a list of embeds, see the documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.embeds

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
history = await channel.history(limit=your_limit).flatten()
```